# get several images' height from the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, image, height

I have images, which are taken from the database. I need to get the height each of them. If I do like that:

```
   $('.find_image_height').height();
```

I takes the first image height, how can I do that. (they array, of course, will help me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getHeights() {
    var heights = [];
    $(".find_image_height").each(function(){
         heights.push($(this).height());
    });
    return heights;
}
```

Comment: I see, but it returns empty array

Comment: wrapped it in a function so it will return the heights for you

Comment: it returns [135, 135, 90, 90, 90] 
[135, 135, 90, 90, 90] 
[135, 135, 90, 90, 90] 
[135, 135, 90, 90, 90] 
[135, 135, 90, 90, 90] how can I get [135,135,90,90,90] ?

Comment: It would only return that if it was being called multiple times. I would have to see your code to be able to tell you what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.map](http://api.jquery.com/map/):

```
$(function() {
  var array = $(".find_image_height").map(function() {
     return $(this).height(); 
  }).get();
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Blade0rz/hgf7J/) is a fiddle to demonstrate.

Comment: thank you, but it returns the number of arrays = number of images

Comment: It returns an array, length of the number of images, containing the height for each. @JonathanCrowe's solution also works fine. Updated to save the output into a variable to make it clearer.